# Random Array Repeats Index Items

Tags: javascript

This code works fine in their example but repeats some of my index items when I try and use it.

```
var lastloaded = 0;
window.onload = loadPages;

    Array.prototype.knuthShuffle = function()
    {
        var i = this.length, j, temp;
        while ( --i )
        {
            j = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i - 1) );
            temp = this[i];
            this[i] = this[j];
            this[j] = temp;
        }
    };

var arr = ["aCard.html", "bCard.html", "cCard.html", "dCard.html"];

function loadPages () {
     arr.knuthShuffle();
    var frame = document.getElementById("frameWrap");
    if (lastloaded+1>arr.length){
        lastloaded = window.location = "greatJob.html";
    }
    frame.src = arr[lastloaded];
    lastloaded++;
};
document.getElementById('tom').onclick = loadPages;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing from this code to keep it from repeating items in my array?

Comment: When I try that code, I never get any repeated elements. I think that your assessment of what's going wrong may be incorrect, as the shuffle code looks fine.  What is it that makes you think you're getting items repeated?

Comment: You mean that if you click `arr.length` times on `tom` that some pages are loaded multible times? If so that's because you shuffle in the `loadPages` (At every click on `tom`)

Comment: Where do you see repetitions in your array? If you mean the reloads, then please notice that "random" does not necessarily mean "changing" (see also http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/).

Comment: When I click on the 'tom' button to go to the next index it sometimes repeats the "bCard.html" or the "dCard.html". So 2 out of the 4 are repeats at some point.

Comment: If you throw a die multiple times, don't you sometimes get repeats? Why should this be any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You have a problem with your declaration of `j` and `temp` which might add up on multiple shuffles and give you some strange behavior.</s>

specifically this line:

```
var i = this.length, j, temp;
```

and these lines:

```
j = Math.floor( Math.random() * (i - 1) );
temp = this[i];
```

The problem here is that you didn't actually declare the `j` and `temp` variables, that's an invalid syntax. Then when declaring them within your loop without the `var` keyword they are treated as global variables. Solvable by modifying the first line into:

```
var j, temp;
var i = this.length;
```

**Edit**: Actually that isn't it, as already pointed out by [t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548628/random-array-repeats-index-items#comment29006503_19548628) every time you click `tom` you're re-shuffling.

What you want to do is shuffle once and use the newly shuffled array every time. So decouple your shuffling from your page loading by taking `arr.knuthShuffle();` out of the `loadPages()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand how your page works, but it seems like it is shuffling the array in order to figure out the next page to go to. This means that it is newly shuffled with every page load, and you therefore have no guarantee as to the uniqueness of the pages - in fact, it would be extremely unlikely for you to get all the unique pages (1 in n!, to be precise)

In order to ensure uniqueness, you MUST save the generated order, not just the index you were at.

Comment: So, do I need to use the knuthShuffle to shuffle the array and store it in a new array and call that new array to use in the loadPages function? I am trying to send the user to the page and have it load up the first randomized item from the array and use the button to continue to go through the array until it ends and then it sends them to a completely different page. I tried to shuffle the original array into a new array but that didn't seem to work either. I am pretty new to this and this has got me baffled.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at your code, just move the `arr.knuthShuffle()` line up one, just outisde the `function loadPages` definition. That way, you only shuffle the array once.